# How can I have my 2016 SharePoint list auto-generate an email when a specific column is populated?

Tags: list, custom-list, task-list

I want to have a "choice" column that allows the user to select the option to inform the other department that this list item has been added or changed.  When there is something chosen into that column, then an automated email message would be sent to a specified email address.  I don't have SharePoint Designer.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an alert on the list:

[Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)